# How to resurrect players sustainably in Divinity: Original Sin?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

The combat is difficultish, and my party members are dropping regularly. The only way I can find to resurrect them is with scrolls purchased in town, but I already bought the 4 that were there.

Now what? How can I rez people when these scrolls run out? Some people in the past have said there is a witchcraft spell that can be bought from the Cyseal potion merchant or Arhu, but it's no longer there in recent versions ( that I can find ).

At the rate I've been going, I will definitely run out of scrolls before I find the next city, and I'll be stuck with permadeath. What do I do?

Answer (score 14):

These scrolls are intended as a measure of last resort, not as a regular tool. That's why there are very few of them.

To get better at combat:

- Make sure you have a full party (4 members)
- Make sure your party skills are well balanced (casters, melee, at least someone with a heal)
- Equip yourself well
- Provision yourself well, with food and potions, and use them during combat (mhmm fish pie)
- Fight smarter, use the elements, don't stand in the fire (or put it out with a rain spell)
- Don't forget scrolls and special arrows (which you can craft)
- A summoned creature (e.g. Spider) works well as an expendable damage sponge
- If an area is just too hard, try an easier one first
- Save early, save often (quickloading is your friend)

> Cyseal's west gate (not the harbor west gate) is probably the easiest area to start with, you'll find level 3 undead right outside the gate.

**Update:** Watch your enemies and learn.

> Undead get healed from poison, but their bones burn well and the fire burns up the poison puddles. The burning legion is immune to fire, but very susceptible to being frozen (Rain + Chill). Ghosts like to use cold spells, so give them some heat.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a resurrection spell from the potions seller in the Cyseal market, I believe