# How to revive outside of combat?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I'm playing Divinity: Original Sin Enhanced Edition.

If one of my party members dies outside of combat (for example while walking through fire while exploring), **can I revive them without having to spend a resurrection scroll and without having the spell yet?**

I have read these scrolls are rather hard to come by.
The skill is apparently only available from level 16.

**Is the penalty for death outside of combat as harsh as in combat?**

[This is a useful related question but does not provide a direct answer.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174957/how-to-resurrect-players-sustainably-in-divinity-original-sin)

Comment: Fun fact: I died by throwing a burning candle in the gas emitters in the tutorial dungeon, causing an infinite series of explosions and coming a bit too close to pick it up again.

Comment: The scrolls are not hard to come by btw, unless your entire team is dying constantly.

Answer (score 4):

Reviving outside of combat is the same as reviving during combat - you'll (generally) require a Resurrection Scroll.  I'm something like 30 hours into the game and I have yet to see a spell book for resurrection, so I have to imagine it's quite rare and high level.

However, my suggestion would be to save (quicksave with F5 on PC!) often, and reload if you do something catastrophically stupid that you'd like to undo.  I saved every time I cleared a combat encounter or right before approaching/interacting with NPCs.  You can save quite a bit of cash and scrolls in this manner.

That said, I found that the Alchemy vendor in Cyseal would have her consumables restocked frequently, so I was able to buy scrolls and other things (lockpicks, trap disarm kits) from her whenever I was low.

Answer (score 1):

3 options- reloading game or using scroll or high levl spell, no way to resurrect
if one of your main characters die, and ur wondering whether you have to backtrack to them when u finally do find a resurruct spell , when you travel to homestead, the other main character in your team will travel with you as a ash heap.